# Octave, finding the maximum of a numeric function

Tags: function, octave, numeric

I am trying to compute the maximum value of the solution of a system with two ODEs using Octave. I have firstly solved the system itself:

```
function xdot = f (x,t)

a1=0.00875;
a2=0.075;
b1=7.5;
b2=2.5;
d1=0.0001;
d2=0.0001;
g=4*10^(-8);
K1=5000;
K2=2500;
n=2;
m=2;

xdot = zeros(2,1);

xdot(1) = a1+b1*x(1)^n/(K1^n+x(1)^n)-g*x(1)*x(2)-d1*x(1);
xdot(2) = a2+b2*x(1)^m/(K2^m+x(1)^m)-d2*x(2);

endfunction

t = linspace(0, 5000, 200)';
x0 = [1000; 1000];
x = lsode ("f", x0, t);

set term dumb;
plot(t,x);
```

But now I do not know how to compute the maximum value of the two functions (numerical ones) obtained as solutions of the system. I have searched in the Internet but I haven't found what I want... I only have found the function fminbnd for the minimum of a function on an interval...

Is it possible to compute the maximum value of a numeric function with Octave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you know how to find the minimum of a function, you also know how to find its maximum: just look for the minimum of -f.

However, `fminbnd` is designed for functions that can be evaluated at any given point. What you have is just a vector of 200 points. In principle, you could use interpolation to get a function and then maximize that. But this is not really needed, because all the information you have is in that matrix x anyway, so it makes sense to just take the maximum value there. Like this:

```
[x1m, i1] = max(x(:,1));
[x2m, i2] = max(x(:,2));
disp(sprintf('Maximum of x1 is %f attained at t = %f', x1m, t(i1)));
disp(sprintf('Maximum of x1 is %f attained at t = %f', x2m, t(i2)));
```